# only part of a href link is active

Tags: html, css, href

I'm building an HTML, CSS thumbnail grid, with rotating thumbs, on the back of the thumbs is a href link. For some reason only part of the link is clickable.

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
<div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
        front
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        back
         <p><a href="index.html">Find out more</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brm3z2dk/3/

Comment: I am able to click any where in the link text..

Comment: @Rex I experience the same issue in Chrome (half link deactivated)

Comment: Link seems to work only over the 're' in Chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [webkit transform blocking link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886656/webkit-transform-blocking-link)

Comment: apart from the duplicated question, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514576/css-3d-transform-unable-to-click-link) too

Comment: use `transform: rotateY(-180deg);` on class `.back` see demo. http://jsfiddle.net/brm3z2dk/11/

Comment: thanks Raptor - transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(-1px);

Comment: and Kheema - transform: rotateY(-180deg); works too

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your css file OR Append `.back`

```
.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
 width: 200px;
 height: 150px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: rgb(29, 140, 194);
 font-size: 22px;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.1;
 }
```

I added just `translateZ(1px)` to transform.

## Working JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2a8y5x3t/

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole div as clickable use `onclick="location.href='index.html';"` and updated code is available at `http://jsfiddle.net/brm3z2dk/7/`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `transform: rotateY(-180deg);` on class `.back` see **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brm3z2dk/11/)**.

```
.back {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);/*change from 180 to -180deg*/
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
padding:10px;
background-color:#1d8cc2;
font-size: 22px;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 1.1;
}
```

Comment: @user1319836 you may accept the answer here so this question will helpful in near future for users experiencing same issue.